# Magento - I deleted a website by accident

Tags: magento

I was going to delete a store view for a particular language in Magento.

I deleted the website view by accident. Luckily I made a back-up just moments before. The tables 'core_config_data' and 'core_websites' have been restored and it seems the website is working properly.

However I need to be 100% sure that no other data is missing. Magento does state:

'Removing a website does not lead to the removal of the information associated with (eg categories, products, etc.), but the removal can not be undone. We recommend that you back up your database before performing the removal.'

I need to know in which tables data is removed when you deleted a website view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest is to restore your full database. If you delete a website all the stores associated to it are deleted and so all all the product values set for those specific store views.

For example if you had a product named 'Something' but on a store view from the website you delete it had the name 'Something else' then you will lose this. If you restored only the store views the name of that product on the specific store view will be 'Something'.